# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "что ли"?

Tags: пунктуация

*- Попробовать **что ли** на ходу в нее запрыгнуть, - вяло промямлил он.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Чтобы выяснить, «что ли» выделяется запятыми или нет, надо запомнить, что выражение относится к модальным частицам, которые выражают неуверенность, предположение или усиливают сомнение, когда оно выражено другими словами. Поэтому перед «что ли» запятая ставится всегда.](https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/chto-li.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***– Попробовать, что ли, на ходу в нее запрыгнуть, – вяло промямлил он.***